# IBM WebSphere Out Of Memory Error when running WASPostUpgrade.sh

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-portal

I'm getting an OutOfMemoryError error when running the WASPostUpgrade.sh task during a portal migration from version 6.1.5 to 7.0.  Below is the javacore file generated.  I've tried adjusting the -Xmx heap argument various times, but it keeps failing.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
0SECTION       TITLE subcomponent dump routine
NULL           ===============================
1TISIGINFO     Dump Event "systhrow" (00040000) Detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" received 
1TIDATETIME    Date:                 2012/03/16 at 09:43:13
1TIFILENAME    Javacore filename:    /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/javacore.20120316.094301.3773.0003.txt
1TIREQFLAGS    Request Flags: 0x81 (exclusive+preempt)
1TIPREPSTATE   Prep State: 0x14 (exclusive_vm_access+heap_prepared)
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0SECTION       GPINFO subcomponent dump routine
NULL           ================================
2XHOSLEVEL     OS Level         : Linux 2.6.18-53.el5
2XHCPUS        Processors -
3XHCPUARCH       Architecture   : x86
3XHNUMCPUS       How Many       : 2
3XHNUMASUP       NUMA is either not supported or has been disabled by user
NULL           
1XHERROR2      Register dump section only produced for SIGSEGV, SIGILL or SIGFPE.
NULL           
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0SECTION       ENVINFO subcomponent dump routine
NULL           =================================
1CIJAVAVERSION JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Linux x86-32 build jvmxi3260sr7-20100219_54097
1CIVMVERSION   VM build 20100219_054097
1CIJITVERSION  JIT enabled, AOT enabled - r9_20091123_13891
1CIGCVERSION   GC - 20100216_AA
1CIRUNNINGAS   Running as a standalone JVM
1CICMDLINE     /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/java -Dosgi.install.area=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer -Dosgi.configuration.area=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/configuration -Dws.output.encoding=console -DKeepProfileName=true -Dcom.ibm.websphere.migration.serverRoot=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer -Dcom.ibm.jsse2.checkRevocation=false -Dcom.ibm.security.enableCRLDP=false -Dcom.ibm.ws.migration.currentProfileLogLocation=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile -Dcom.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL=file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/properties/ssl.client.props -Dws.ext.dirs=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/lib:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/classes:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/installedChannels:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/ext:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/web/help:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime -Duser.install.root=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile -Dwas.install.root=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Xj9 -Xquickstart -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/properties/wsjaas_client.conf -Djava.util.logging.manager=com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WsLogManager -Djava.util.logging.configureByServer=true -classpath /opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/properties:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/startup.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/bootstrap.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/lmproxy.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/urlprotocols.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/lib/tools.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/derby/lib/derby.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/derby/migration/migratetoderby.jar com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher -nosplash -application com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher com.ibm.ws.migration.WASPostUpgrade /opt/IBM/WebSphere/wps61migration/backup_dir/ -profileName wp_profile -oldProfile wp_profile -username wpsadmin -password 38wp41ad -includeApps true -backupConfig false
1CIJAVAHOMEDIR Java Home Dir:   /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre
1CIJAVADLLDIR  Java DLL Dir:    /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/bin
1CISYSCP       Sys Classpath:   /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/vm.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/annotation.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/beans.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/java.util.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/jndi.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/logging.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/security.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/sql.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ibmorb.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ibmorbapi.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ibmcfw.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/rt.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/charsets.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/resources.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ibmpkcs.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ibmcertpathfw.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ibmjgssfw.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ibmjssefw.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ibmsaslfw.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ibmjcefw.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ibmjgssprovider.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ibmjsseprovider2.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ibmcertpathprovider.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ibmxmlcrypto.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/management-agent.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/xml.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/jlm.jar;/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/javascript.jar;
1CIUSERARGS    UserArgs:
2CIUSERARG               -Xjcl:jclscar_24
2CIUSERARG               -Dcom.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/i386
2CIUSERARG               -Dsun.boot.library.path=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/i386
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.library.path=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.home=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.ext.dirs=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ext
2CIUSERARG               -Duser.dir=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin
2CIUSERARG               _j2se_j9=71168 0x0086D3E0
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.runtime.version=pxi3260sr7ifx-20100707_01 (SR7)
2CIUSERARG               -Xdump
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.class.path=.
2CIUSERARG               -Dosgi.install.area=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
2CIUSERARG               -Dosgi.configuration.area=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/configuration
2CIUSERARG               -Dws.output.encoding=console
2CIUSERARG               -DKeepProfileName=true
2CIUSERARG               -Dcom.ibm.websphere.migration.serverRoot=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
2CIUSERARG               -Dcom.ibm.jsse2.checkRevocation=false
2CIUSERARG               -Dcom.ibm.security.enableCRLDP=false
2CIUSERARG               -Dcom.ibm.ws.migration.currentProfileLogLocation=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile
2CIUSERARG               -Dcom.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL=file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/properties/ssl.client.props
2CIUSERARG               -Dws.ext.dirs=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/lib:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/classes:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/installedChannels:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/ext:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/web/help:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime
2CIUSERARG               -Duser.install.root=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile
2CIUSERARG               -Dwas.install.root=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
2CIUSERARG               -Xms512m
2CIUSERARG               -Xmx1024m
2CIUSERARG               -Xquickstart
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/properties/wsjaas_client.conf
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.util.logging.manager=com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WsLogManager
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.util.logging.configureByServer=true
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.class.path=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/properties:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/startup.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/bootstrap.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/lmproxy.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/urlprotocols.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/lib/tools.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/derby/lib/derby.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/derby/migration/migratetoderby.jar
2CIUSERARG               -Dsun.java.command=com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher -nosplash -application com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher com.ibm.ws.migration.WASPostUpgrade /opt/IBM/WebSphere/wps61migration/backup_dir/ -profileName wp_profile -oldProfile wp_profile -username wpsadmin -password 38wp41ad -includeApps true -backupConfig false
2CIUSERARG               -Dsun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
2CIUSERARG               -Dsun.java.launcher.pid=3773
2CIUSERARG               _port_library 0x0086F7E0
2CIUSERARG               _org.apache.harmony.vmi.portlib 0x09F6D718
NULL
1CIUSERLIMITS  User Limits (in bytes except for NOFILE and NPROC)
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
NULL           type                            soft limit           hard limit
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_AS                        unlimited            unlimited
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_CORE                              0                    0
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_CPU                       unlimited            unlimited
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_DATA                      unlimited            unlimited
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_FSIZE                     unlimited            unlimited
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_LOCKS                     unlimited            unlimited
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_MEMLOCK                       32768                32768
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_NOFILE                       200000               200000
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_NPROC                         10240                10240
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_RSS                       unlimited            unlimited
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_STACK                      10485760            unlimited
NULL
1CIENVVARS     Environment Variables
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2CIENVVAR      OSGI_INSTALL=-Dosgi.install.area=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
2CIENVVAR      WAS_USER_SCRIPT=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/bin/setupCmdLine.sh
2CIENVVAR      HOSTNAME=vmwps03t
2CIENVVAR      CONFIG_ROOT=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/config
2CIENVVAR      WAS_NODE=vmwps02t
2CIENVVAR      TERM=xterm
2CIENVVAR      SHELL=/bin/bash
2CIENVVAR      HISTSIZE=1000
2CIENVVAR      SSH_CLIENT=10.14.0.183 3758 22
2CIENVVAR      USER_INSTALL_PROP=-Duser.install.root=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile
2CIENVVAR      JAVA_HIGH_ZIPFDS=200
2CIENVVAR      OLDPWD=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
2CIENVVAR      SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
2CIENVVAR      INV_PRF_SPECIFIED=false
2CIENVVAR      QUALIFYNAMES=-qualifyHomeName
2CIENVVAR      CLIENT_CONNECTOR_INSTALL_ROOT=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/installedConnectors
2CIENVVAR      OSGI_CFG=-Dosgi.configuration.area=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/configuration
2CIENVVAR      USER=wpsadmin
2CIENVVAR      LS_COLORS=no=00:fi=00:di=00;34:ln=00;36:pi=40;33:so=00;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=01;05;37;41:mi=01;05;37;41:ex=00;32:*.cmd=00;32:*.exe=00;32:*.com=00;32:*.btm=00;32:*.bat=00;32:*.sh=00;32:*.csh=00;32:*.tar=00;31:*.tgz=00;31:*.arj=00;31:*.taz=00;31:*.lzh=00;31:*.zip=00;31:*.z=00;31:*.Z=00;31:*.gz=00;31:*.bz2=00;31:*.bz=00;31:*.tz=00;31:*.rpm=00;31:*.cpio=00;31:*.jpg=00;35:*.gif=00;35:*.bmp=00;35:*.xbm=00;35:*.xpm=00;35:*.png=00;35:*.tif=00;35:
2CIENVVAR      TMOUT=600
2CIENVVAR      USER_INSTALL_ROOT=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile
2CIENVVAR      SERVERSAS=-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/properties/sas.server.props
2CIENVVAR      NLSPATH=/usr/lib/locale/%L/LC_MESSAGES/%N:/usr/lib/locale/%L/LC_MESSAGES/%N:
2CIENVVAR      MAIL=/var/spool/mail/wpsadmin
2CIENVVAR      PATH=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/ibm_bin:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/bin:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/ibm_bin:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/wpsadmin/bin:/usr/IBM:/admin:.
2CIENVVAR      WAS_CLASSPATH=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/properties:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/startup.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/bootstrap.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/lmproxy.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/urlprotocols.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/lib/tools.jar
2CIENVVAR      INPUTRC=/etc/inputrc
2CIENVVAR      PWD=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin
2CIENVVAR      NO_DFT_PRF_EXISTS=false
2CIENVVAR      WAS_LIBPATH=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin
2CIENVVAR      JAVA_HOME=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java
2CIENVVAR      LANG=en_US.UTF-8
2CIENVVAR      CLIENTSSL=-Dcom.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL=file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/properties/ssl.client.props
2CIENVVAR      WAS_CELL=vmwps02t
2CIENVVAR      SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
2CIENVVAR      SHLVL=3
2CIENVVAR      HOME=/root
2CIENVVAR      CLIENTSOAP=-Dcom.ibm.SOAP.ConfigURL=file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/properties/soap.client.props
2CIENVVAR      WAS_HOME=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
2CIENVVAR      LOGNAME=wpsadmin
2CIENVVAR      WAS_LOGGING=-Djava.util.logging.manager=com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WsLogManager -Djava.util.logging.configureByServer=true
2CIENVVAR      SSH_CONNECTION=10.14.0.183 3758 10.30.0.30 22
2CIENVVAR      WAS_EXT_DIRS=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/lib:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/classes:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/installedChannels:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/ext:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/web/help:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime
2CIENVVAR      LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
2CIENVVAR      WAS_USER_SCRIPT_FILE_NOT_EXISTS=false
2CIENVVAR      ITP_LOC=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp
2CIENVVAR      CLIENTSAS=-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/properties/sas.client.props
2CIENVVAR      STDINCLIENTSAS=-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/properties/sas.stdinclient.props
2CIENVVAR      G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
2CIENVVAR      _=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/java
2CIENVVAR      IBM_JAVA_COMMAND_LINE=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/java -Dosgi.install.area=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer -Dosgi.configuration.area=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/configuration -Dws.output.encoding=console -DKeepProfileName=true -Dcom.ibm.websphere.migration.serverRoot=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer -Dcom.ibm.jsse2.checkRevocation=false -Dcom.ibm.security.enableCRLDP=false -Dcom.ibm.ws.migration.currentProfileLogLocation=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile -Dcom.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL=file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/properties/ssl.client.props -Dws.ext.dirs=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/lib:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/classes:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/installedChannels:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/ext:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/web/help:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime -Duser.install.root=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile -Dwas.install.root=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Xj9 -Xquickstart -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/properties/wsjaas_client.conf -Djava.util.logging.manager=com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WsLogManager -Djava.util.logging.configureByServer=true -classpath /opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/properties:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/startup.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/bootstrap.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/lmproxy.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/urlprotocols.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/lib/tools.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/derby/lib/derby.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/derby/migration/migratetoderby.jar com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher -nosplash -application com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher com.ibm.ws.migration.WASPostUpgrade /opt/IBM/WebSphere/wps61migration/backup_dir/ -profileName wp_profile -oldProfile wp_profile -username wpsadmin -password 38wp41ad -includeApps true -backupConfig false
NULL           
1CIJVMMI       JVM Monitoring Interface (JVMMI)
NULL           ------------------------
2CIJVMMIOFF    [not available]
NULL           
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0SECTION       MEMINFO subcomponent dump routine
NULL           =================================
1STHEAPFREE    Bytes of Heap Space Free: 0 
1STHEAPALLOC   Bytes of Heap Space Allocated: 40000000
```

Comment: I guess I'd try maxing out -Xmx (somewhere around -Xmx1810m on 32-bit Windows for IBM J9), and if that doesn't work, then either your cell/config is huge or you've encountered a product issue and should open a PMR with IBM.

Answer (score 1):

Check your ulimit to ensure the process is not constrained on real memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known issue, see this [technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21199311).

Comment: Ultimately, the technote just recommends the user update -Xmx (or bump -Xmx for wsadmin, but the javacore snippet shows OOM in WASPostUpgrade itself), and OP has already bumped to -Xmx1024m.